# How to scan to PDF v1.5 or higher

Tags: pdf, scanner, brother, simplescan

On Ubuntu 20.04 I am using `simple-scan` utility together the official driver for my `Brother` scanner, that is [this driver](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=ads2400n_all&os=128&dlid=dlf104033_000&flang=4&type3=566&dlang=true).
The generated PDFs are of v1.3, however my desired version is 1.5 or above. For now work-around this by printing to file the v1.3 pdfs right after. How is it possible to upgrade version of the generated pdf directly out of `simple-scan`?